# How do I get my subsection to not appear bold and with no period at the end?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, sections-paragraphs

This is what I have for my codes:

```
\section{MAIN RESULTS}
\subsection{Graphical Analysis}
```

I am getting this in the pdf: [image]

Instead I want the subsection in Italic non-bold form with no period at the end.

This is what I have in my preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt,reqno]{amsart}

% Packages
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{;}{,}{,}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage[
  colorlinks=true,
  citecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=blue,
  linkcolor=blue
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{ amssymb }
\usepackage{caption} \captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=normalfont,labelsep=colon}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\pagestyle{plain}

\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{12pt}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

\allowdisplaybreaks[4]

% Commenting/debugging
\let\IG\iffalse
\let\ENDIG\fi

%% Shortcuts
\newcommand{\td}[2]{\dfrac{d #1}{d #2}}
\newcommand{\std}[2]{\dfrac{d^2 #1}{d {#2}^2}}
\newcommand{\ctd}[3]{\dfrac{d^2 #1}{d #2 d #3}}

\newcommand{\pd}[2]{\dfrac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\newcommand{\spd}[2]{\dfrac{\partial^2 #1}{\partial {#2}^2}}
\newcommand{\cpd}[3]{\dfrac{\partial^2 #1}{\partial #2 \partial #3}}

\newcommand{\pdi}[2]{\partial #1/\partial #2}

\newcommand{\LR}{\Leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\Lg}{\mathcal{L}}
\newcommand{\half}{\tfrac{1}{2}}
\newcommand{\eqp}{\phantom{=}}
\newcommand{\eqs}{\buildrel s \over =}
\newcommand{\me}{\mathrm{e}}
```

Comment: `titlesec`? (Not sure if it agrees with `amsart`?)

Comment: @cfr Tried it, but didn't work.

Comment: @cfr AMS document classes and `titlesec` are not compatible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The formatting you are trying to change was tailored by the AMS to suit its editorial style; since AMS document classes do things in their own way, such changes cannot be made using packages that would cooperate with standard classes and some redefinitions of internal commands will be required.

Redefining `\subsection` you can get non-bolded, italics font for subsections; a redefinition of `\@sect` to suppress `\@addpunct.` will kill the final period.

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{1}%
  \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{-.5em}%
  {\normalfont\itshape}}
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
  \edef\@toclevel{\ifnum#2=\@m 0\else\number#2\fi}%
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \let\@secnumber\@empty
  \else \@xp\let\@xp\@secnumber\csname the#1\endcsname\fi
  \@tempskipa #5\relax
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
    \let\@svsec\@empty
  \else
    \refstepcounter{#1}%
    \edef\@secnumpunct{%
      \ifdim\@tempskipa>\z@ % not a run-in section heading
        \@ifnotempty{#8}{.\@nx\enspace}%
      \else
        \@ifempty{#8}{.}{.\@nx\enspace}%
      \fi
    }%
    \@ifempty{#8}{%
      \ifnum #2=\tw@ \def\@secnumfont{\bfseries}\fi}{}%
    \protected@edef\@svsec{%
      \ifnum#2<\@m
        \@ifundefined{#1name}{}{%
          \ignorespaces\csname #1name\endcsname\space
        }%
      \fi
      \@seccntformat{#1}%
    }%
  \fi
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@ % then this is not a run-in section heading
    \begingroup #6\relax
    \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}{\interlinepenalty\@M #8\par}%
    \endgroup
    \ifnum#2>\@m \else \@tocwrite{#1}{#8}\fi
  \else
  \def\@svsechd{#6\hskip #3\@svsec
    \@ifnotempty{#8}{\ignorespaces#8\unskip
       %\@addpunct.
       }%
    \ifnum#2>\@m \else \@tocwrite{#1}{#8}\fi
  }%
  \fi
  \global\@nobreaktrue
  \@xsect{#5}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{MAIN RESULTS}
\subsection{Graphical Analysis}

\end{document}
```

A patch can reduce the code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{1}%
  \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{-.5em}%
  {\normalfont\itshape}}
\patchcmd{\@sect}
  {\@addpunct.}
  {}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{MAIN RESULTS}
\subsection{Graphical Analysis}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks. It's actually a lot of coding for a little thing.

Comment: @user36829 You're welcome! I edited the answer to add the italics for subsection titles.

Comment: @user36829 I've added a shorter version (patching `\@sect`) in my newly updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that's based on loading the `etoolbox` package and executing its `\patchcmd` macro a couple of times.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,reqno]{amsart}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\subsection}{\bfseries}{\itshape}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@sect}{\@addpunct.}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{2} % just for this example
\section{Main Results}
\subsection{Graphical Analysis}
\end{document}
```